# Trying to grab the post ID from the $post object and it returns empty. Globalization of the variable does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, marketo

I am working on a WordPress plugin to create a new email in Marketo after a user publishes a new post for the first time. I can successfully create the email with all of the information I need except for the featured image. I'm using get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id) to grab the URL of the image, but it seems that $post->ID is coming up empty so get_the_post_thumbnail_url() won't work. I've seen people with similar problems suggesting to globalize the post object (I did this by creating adding global $post outside of the function itself), but that still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
function mkto_new_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post ){
  if ('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status ){
    $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); 
    $replyEmail = get_the_author_meta('user_email', $author_id);
    $fromName = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);
  
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;

    $id = $post->ID; //this comes up empty
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id);

    $description = "Email created from post: {$title}";
    $subject = "New blog post from {$fromName}: {$title}";
    $postFields = "name={$description}&template=1350&folder=%7B%22id%22%3A%221761%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22Program%22%7D&subject={$subject}&fromName={$fromName}&fromEmail={$replyEmail}&replyEmail={$replyEmail}&description={$description}";
    
    $token = mkto_get_token();
    $url = "https://monkeyfoo.mktorest.com/rest/asset/v1/emails.json?access_token={$token}";

    $curl = curl_init();
  
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    $data = json_decode($response, true);    
    $emailID = $data['result'][0]['id'];

    mkto_update_title($emailID, $token, $title);
    mkto_update_content($emailID, $token, $excerpt, $image);
  }    
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'mkto_new_post', 10, 3);
```

Comment: If anyone else knows a way to grab the featured image, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2):

You have access to `post object` and already used it. If `$title = $post->post_title` and `$excerpt = $post->post_excerpt` worked and returned the `title` and `excerpt` then, there **MUST** be an `ID` too!

- How do you know `$id = $post->ID` is empty? How did you test it?
- Does the post have any image attached to it? First, make sure that your post has actually an image attached to it because it's highly likely that the `ID` does not return empty.
- Also, what is `mkto_update_content` function that you're passing your `$image` to? Where does it come from? Is it sort of a custom helper function?

Also, in addition to `get_the_post_thumbnail_url`, you could try this:

```php
$id = $post->ID;

$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($id);

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'thumbnail');
```

If you still can't get it to work, you could add another condition to your `if` statement to make sure `$post->ID` returns the id:

```php
if ('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && $post->ID)
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I have access to the post object, I should be able to get the ID easily. The mkto_update_content function is my own function that makes a curl post to Marketo and sets the main content of the email, including the image. I know the ID is empty because I've tried to display the variable in a <p> in that email and it's blank.

Comment: In theory, wordpress database is a `relational` database. The `id` of a post is the `primary key` and can **NOT** be `null`/`empty` and it must be unique. If a post has `title` and/or `content`, it **MUST** have an `id` assigned to it because `id` is the `primary key`.  So just to debug your code, and since you're getting the `$title`, i'd append `$id` to the `$title` and see if returns it or not. Like so:  `$title = $id." - ".$post->post_title;`. Of curse, first get the `id`, then append it to `title`, otherwise it returns `null`. `$id = $post->ID; $title = $id." - ".$post->post_title;`

Comment: I totally agree with you! It MUST have an ID, so why can't I get it? I will try some of things you've suggested and get back.